# General Android GPS Behavior

Tags: android

I'm about to start using location services, but have a general question about how the GPS receiver is used in Android. When GPS is enabled on a device, is it active right away (i.e., getting a satellite fix) or it is active only when an application has requested location updates?

The reason I'm asking is because my experience with various personal GPS units is that when you first activate them, there is a considerable time lag before it gets locked in and figures out where it is (my Garmin Forerunner can take a couple of minutes sometimes to get a fix).

So how does Android get the initial GPS lock, and can it maintain that lock even if an app is only getting position updates a couple of minutes apart? Does an app typically experience a big time lag before the first position notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does take some time to get a GPS fix. The exact amount of time would vary between devices I believe but it's not a couple of minutes. Usually a few seconds in my usage - both in Google Maps and my app.

You get GPS updates in your app only when you explicitly request for them. The frequency of the updates depend on the parameters with which you initialize the LocationListener. If you have kept the GPS on and then you start your app, then the process will be quicker.

You can also fetch a last known best estimate if you want to get started right away and do not want to wait for an exact fix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is independent from the device you're using but Android should behave like that:

If GPS is enabled, this does not mean that is is really in use. Enabled only means that it can be used by an application or whatever. So your assumption is true, it takes some time to receive a signal. However on my device (HTC Desire) this is generally done very quick. But sometimes I also noticed that it took 2-3 minutes. But that I think is dependent on the device, the weather conditions, your environment (near a big building for example) and last but not least the cosmic radiation.

The best solution I think is to use a [GPSStatusListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX) to check how many satellites you are connected to and check for the first fix.

Answer (score 0):

The GPS functionality is the same as any other in that the lag time or wait time to acquire satellites, often three or more is the same. Wait time is a function of how far away you are from your last location >400 miles and it's line of sight to each satellite.

As far as GPS updating your app. Read about LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates. You will control how and when you update your location and how you use Location Services. The GPS behaves as any other, just remember battery and time to locate in Android are the main concerns. You will want your app to respond fast and using GPS can be slow in terms of locking on and updating.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the phone I've been developing on is that the initial fix does take a little while if the GPS functionality was turned off previously. However, once it does find a fix, it triggers the onlocationchange event quite frequently.

Comment: Exactly, You should be doing something else in your app so the user is not waiting on your GPS Lock

Comment: As a follow up to apesa comment, a "searching for fix" message is a good thing to show. My application runs as a service so they don't need to see that ;)